# mimic bdh function fill down

Tags: vba, excel, bloomberg

When a query is entered into the Bloomberg BDH function in Excel it automatically populates the selected cell, and cells below with the requested data.

I am trying to create a function that does something similar (albeit with a different source of data). How does the BDH function circumvent the typical restriction within a user defined function of modifying other cells when it fills down the queried data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it in a two-stage process:

1. Your function calls another process to compute values and return only the 1st element of the array to be returned (could be "#NA #NA" or the date or price, etc.
2. The called process can be running in a separate RTD server (check out Real Time Data server) or a separate process which links to your spreadsheet via DDE. (Bloomberg uses DDE for some functions, RTD for the others, I think)
3. That way when you call a function, the first value is returned immediately (i.e. the answer, or "#NA Requesting Data..." and then when the RTD server fetches the required data the answer to this function changes to whatever the top-left array element is, and the rest of the cells are populated via DDE/RTD.

Simple examples of setting up a RTD server are found on Microsoft's knowledge base. Also, lots of examples using DDE (an older, but very popular technology for financial data exchange using Excel, even today) are available upon Googling.

A simple filler application can be built using C# or VB.net Interop (search again for examples).

Hope this helps.

**Edit**: You can also do this completely using VBA by using some clever combination of the OnTime functionality (see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx) and combining it with DDE driven from a separate spreadsheet (look up Tushar Mehta DDE clock, a very old example, but some things never change!)

Comment: I am not sure if this is quite what I was looking for - my problem is not in the pulling of real time data (the other Excel sheet where I will be querying the data from is static). My issues lies in the ability to write a single query, have it find a selection of cells in another document, and fill those in using a single user defined function, much in the way a BDH structure does

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're looking for. And RTD or DDE (especially DDE) will do exactly that. Using Spreadsheet1, for e.g. you can manipulate cells in a separate spreadsheet2 even if the spreadsheet is currently open. Do look up the DDE example. That one will let you run a live timer (changing cell A1 of a spreadsheet which is open) in one open spreadsheet, driven from code in another.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now that I have looked up the DDE example it is much more clear.

Comment: Yes. Bloomberg uses DDE for BDH and RTD for BDP functions (and a combination of the two for BDS depending on whether you want your answer in a single cell or not)... which is my guess, but correlates to the functions' behavior. In fact, in the Bloomberg Terminal settings, you can turn DDE on or off, which gives a further hint as to how it's implemented.

Comment: You have any links? I cannot find anything useful on DDE or RTD with code examples I can understand. I looked up this Tushar thing, and I could not find anything related to this...